# android Mediaplayer can not work in emulator

Tags: android, media-player

I'm begginer in android Programming
My Question is...

I wanted to play backgroud Music.
So I read a code like this

---

```
public class Welcome extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    MediaPlayer player;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);        

        player=MediaPlayer.create(Welcome.this, R.raw.song);
        player.start();
```

---

But this code doesn't work in emulator. Error occured...

My Logcat is here..

---

```
03-05 15:36:36.588: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(954): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-05 15:36:36.588: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(954): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{younkyung.app.lord_of_spelling/younkyung.app.lord_of_spelling.Welcome}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-05 15:36:36.588: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(954):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
03-05 15:36:36.588: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(954):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
03-05 15:36:36.588: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(954):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
03-05 15:36:36.588: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(954):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
03-05 15:36:36.588: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(954):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-05 15:36:36.588: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(954):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-05 15:36:36.588: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(954):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
03-05 15:36:36.588: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(954):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-05 15:36:36.588: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(954):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-05 15:36:36.588: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(954):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
03-05 15:36:36.588: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(954):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
03-05 15:36:36.588: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(954):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-05 15:36:36.588: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(954): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-05 15:36:36.588: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(954):     at younkyung.app.lord_of_spelling.Welcome.onCreate(Welcome.java:25)
03-05 15:36:36.588: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(954):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-05 15:36:36.588: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(954):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
03-05 15:36:36.588: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(954):     ... 11 more
```

---

I cannot understand what's wrong...
Please Help..! ...

Comment: You have a null pointer exception at line 25 of your onCreate method.  Use the debugger and insert a breakpoint at the line and find out what object is null.

Comment: What filetype is the song you are trying to play?

Comment: I used wma. I read a android API. It explained the cycle of MediaPlayer work. maybe... Do I have to use setDataSource() and prepare() first?... I have to try

Comment: I dont think you can directly play wma audio file on MediaPlayer, take a look at this link http://www.rbgrn.net/content/307-light-racer-20-days-61-64-completion

Answer (score 1):

You need to use one of the [supported file formats](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/guide/appendix/media-formats.html). WMA is not one of them.

Comment: @Ashley If you find this answer helpful, you should hit the checkbox icon near this question. Thanks.